# How does Django foreign key access work

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

Say I have a model like this.

```
class Job(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Contacts, null=True)
```

and lets say I have job j. I know I can access the client belonging to j like this

```
 j.client
```

but there is also

```
 j.client_id
```

So my question is how does accessing j.client work?

Does django store client__id then when j.client is called it does a query to find the correct object?

Or is the object reference stored to j and accessing client__id is getting the id from the Contact object?

I've looked around the source code a bit but couldn't find the answer to my question

Comment: possible duplicate of [When does Django look up the primary key of foreign keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631211/when-does-django-look-up-the-primary-key-of-foreign-keys)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is explained in the docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#database-representation

In the database there is only `client_id` field (single underscore)

On the model instance you will have `client` attribute, when you access it this will cause Django to load the related object from the db and instantiate as another model instance.

You will also have `client_id` attribute (one underscore) which has the primary key value of the related object, as stored in the db field.

When doing ORM queries you are able to use `client__id` (double underscore) syntax to lookup against fields on the related model, eg you could also do `client__name` if `Client` model had a `name` field. This will become a SQL JOIN query across both models.

eg

```
Job.objects.get(client__id=1)
Job.objects.filter(client__name='John')

client = Client.objects.get(pk=1)
Job.objects.get(client=client)
```

Comment: Yea I noticed my mistake and edited the question to correctly reflect the access. Awesome this is the confirmation I was looking for. I suspected this was the case, thanks mate!

Answer (score 11):

What you are probably talking about is `client` and `client_id` (single underscore).

The `client_id` attribute is a regular (integer) attribute. This is the foreign key that is saved to the database. You will only ever see a `client_id` column in the database, even though you specify the `ForeignKey` as `client`.

The `client` attribute is an object descriptor instance. It is a special class that overrides the `__get__` and `__set__` methods, so settings and accessing that attributes invokes that class's methods. This is the magic that gives you access to the actual related model instance. `__get__` will retrieve the correct model instance from the database if it isn't loaded already, based on the `client_id` attribute. `__set__` will also set the `client_id` attribute to the primary key of the related object, so that `client_id` is always up-to-date.

Note that this attribute is also available in query lookups, and is quite handy. E.g., if you have just the primary key of a foreign object, and not the model instance itself, the following queries look very similar:

```
job = Job.objects.filter(client__id=pk)
job = Job.objects.filter(client_id=pk)
```

However, underneath the first query accesses an attribute on the related object (double underscore) and performs an `OUTER JOIN`. The second query only ever accesses a local attribute, thus not having to perform the `OUTER JOIN` statement and saving performance.

Comment: Yep I already changed my question, noticed the mistake a minute after I posted it. You guys are too fast for me >.< haha

Answer (score 3):

`j.client` gives you the `models.Model` object. You can access it's properties like ...

```
client = j.client

id = client.id
name = client.name
```

But there should not be a `j.client__id` field. You should use `j.client.id` to get the `id` field. Although you can use `j.client__id` field to do filters and such.

So,

```
id = j.client.id # good
id = j.client__id # bad
```

and

```
job = Job.objects.get(client__id=1) # good
job = Job.objects.get(client.id=1) # bad
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to put the extra _
There is a client_id field try it for yourself

Comment: From Django's documentation - "Behind the scenes, Django appends "_id" to the field name to create its database column name. ".

Comment: And I'm unsure why someone would -1 my answer based on wrongly typed question.

Comment: Did you just downvote both other answers because someone downvoted yours?

Comment: I'm upvoting this to counteract the downvote because it was my mistake. If you did down vote the other two please undo that. They are good answers

Comment: I did downvote the original question, but I did not downvote the other answers. It was somebody else. I'm undoing the downvote on the question.